# WSO2 ESB 4.5.0 fails to start, hanging after mount to the remote registry

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm having a problem with ESB start up. It fails right after mounting to the remote repository after the following INFO message, but previously it started without any problems with the same configuration:

```
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-28 15:16:22,604]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent} -  Registry Mode    : READ-WRITE {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent}
```

I have enabled debug and notice some recurring messages that never stop to occur:

```
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-28 15:25:21,926] DEBUG    {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog} -  Total Number of Connections Created      : 598 {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-28 15:25:21,926] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog} -  Total Number of Connections Closed       : 614 {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-28 15:25:21,926] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog} -  Total Number of Connections Committed    : 614 {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-28 15:25:21,926] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog} -  Total Number of Connections Rollbacked   : 0 {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-28 15:25:21,926] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog} -  Total Number of Statements Prepared      : 402 {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-28 15:25:21,926] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog} -  Total Number of Statements Closed        : 402 {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-28 15:25:21,926] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog} -  Total Number of Active Transactions      : 0 {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-28 15:25:22,115] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog} -  Total Number of get calls                : 36 {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-28 15:25:22,115] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog} -  Total Number of put calls                : 0 {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-28 15:25:22,115] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog} -  Total Number of import calls             : 0 {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-28 15:25:22,115] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog} -  Total Number of move calls               : 0 {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-28 15:25:22,115] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog} -  Total Number of copy calls               : 0 {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-28 15:25:22,115] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog} -  Total Number of rename calls             : 0 {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-28 15:25:22,115] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog} -  Total Number of delete calls             : 0 {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-28 15:25:22,116] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog} -  Total Number of addAssociation calls     : 0 {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-28 15:25:22,116] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog} -  Total Number of removeAssociation calls  : 0 {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-28 15:25:22,116] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog} -  Total Number of getAssociations calls    : 0 {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-28 15:25:22,116] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog} -  Total Number of getAllAssociations calls : 0 {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-28 15:25:22,116] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog} -  Total Number of executeQuery calls       : 0 {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-28 15:25:22,116] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog} -  Total Number of resourceExists calls     : 234 {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-28 15:25:22,116] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog} -  Total Number of dump calls               : 0 {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-28 15:25:22,116] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog} -  Total Number of restore calls            : 0 {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-28 15:25:24,262] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil} -  Total Number of Connections Created      : 2 {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-28 15:25:24,262] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil} -  Total Number of Connections Closed       : 12 {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil}
```

The full log is available [here](http://pastebin.com/2i5hExVX)

master-datasource.xml:

```
 <datasource>
        <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
        <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
        <jndiConfig>
            <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/WSO2_ESB?autoReconnect=true</url>
                <username>username</username>
                <password>password</password>
                <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>

    <datasource>
        <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB_GREG</name>
        <description>The datasource used for registry </description>
        <jndiConfig>
            <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB_GREG</name>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/WSO2_REGISTRY?autoReconnect=true</url>
                <username>username</username>
                <password>password</password>
                <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
                <maxactive>50</maxactive>
                <maxwait>60000</maxwait>
                <testonborrow>true</testonborrow>
                <validationquery>SELECT 1</validationquery>
                <validationinterval>30000</validationinterval>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>
```

registry.xml:

```
<currentDBConfig>wso2registry</currentDBConfig>
<readOnly>false</readOnly>
<enableCache>true</enableCache>
<registryRoot>/</registryRoot>

<dbConfig name="wso2registry">
    <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</dataSource>
</dbConfig>

<dbConfig name="wso2registry_mounted">
    <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB_GREG</dataSource>
</dbConfig>

<remoteInstance url="https://localhost:9443/registry">
    <id>wso2_registry_mounted</id>
    <dbConfig>wso2registry_mounted</dbConfig>
    <readOnly>false</readOnly>
    <enableCache>true</enableCache>
    <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
</remoteInstance>

<mount overwrite="true" path="/_system/config">
    <instanceId>wso2_registry_mounted</instanceId>
    <targetPath>/_system/nodes</targetPath>
</mount>

<mount overwrite="true" path="/_system/governance">
    <instanceId>wso2_registry_mounted</instanceId>
    <targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath>
</mount>
```

Did anyone suffered the same issue?

Thanks in advance,
Vladimir.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed tag errors in your configurations.Tags are case sensitive. below tags are wrong in your second data source configuration.

```
<maxactive>50</maxactive>
<maxwait>60000</maxwait>
<testonborrow>true</testonborrow>
<validationquery>SELECT 1</validationquery>
<validationinterval>30000</validationinterval>
```

it should be,

```
<maxActive>50</maxActive>
<maxWait>60000</maxWait>
<testonBorrow>true</testonBorrow>
<validatiOnQuery>SELECT 1</validatiOnQuery>
<validatiOnInterval>30000</validatiOnInterval>
```

Same time you can follow the guide in [1].

1. http://ajithvblogs.blogspot.com/2012/09/create-jdbc-mount-to-wso2-governance.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It started correctly even with the wrong config as it just ignored miscased tags. However the problem still exists.

Comment: can you attach your current registry config?

Answer (score 0):

just had this problem, it was getting stuck at the point where it was trying to mount one of the two mounts we were setting up. we found that by commenting one out it worked.

our end solution to get both mounting was creating a new folder and moving all contents into it, deleting old folder and then renaming the new folder.